# How to cons multiple elements to list?

Tags: elixir

Suppose I have a list and I want to cons two elements to it. I could do this:

`list = [3,4]`

`[1,2,3,4] == [ 1 | [2 | list ] ]`

This is ugly and doesn't extend to `n` elements.

What idiom supports this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple head elements can be added comma-separated.

```elixir
list = [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] == [1, 2 | list]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]
```